# no suitable driver found using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

I was working on a hibernate project in eclipse. I put all of the jars files including Mysql connector jar in the WEB-INF lib folder. When I try to run the code, it throws an error.

Exception

org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:131) org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49) org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125) org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110) org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:304) org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:169) org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67) org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160) org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1363) first.doPost(first.java:37) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Root Cause

java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source) java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source) org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:192) org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:278) org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:297) org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:169) org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67) org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160) org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1363) first.doPost(first.java:37) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwXZb.png)

Here is my configuration:

"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"

"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

```
<session-factory name="factory">

    <property name="connection.driver_class">
        com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

    </property>

    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample</property>

    <property name="connection.username">
        root
    </property>
    <property name="connection.password">
        root
    </property>
    <property name="connection.pool_size">5</property>
    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">
        org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    </property>
    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->

    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <mapping class="user" />

</session-factory>
```

java

Comment: Are you running your web application in a container? If so can you not create a datasource and then configure your hibernate to lookup the connection from the datasource?

Comment: i don't know i'm new in this. i just create dynamic web project. and i'm runing in tomcat. when i run in simple project for hibernate it work fine but. for dynamic i'm getting this error.. help me with this one

Comment: Are you deploying the dynamic web project to an application server? (container)

Comment: yes .i'm running  in tomcat

Comment: You need to follow these instructions to configure a datasource on TomCat https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#JDBC_Data_Sources. Once you have done so, you will need to change your hibernate configuration file to reference the new datasource added. By the way, the reason why your Hibernate isn't working is because the container needs to be aware of the database and drivers associated with it.